# what about enhance template enable_if

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

At first I use the enable_if ,the code I write below **will not** compile,but it seems right in logic,but won't be support by the enable_if implementation in current.

```
  1 
  2 #include <iostream>
  3 using namespace std;
  4 
  5 template<int N>
  6 struct S{
  7                 template<class T>
  8                 typename enable_if<N==1,T>::type
  9                 f(T t) {return 1;};
 10 
 11                 template<class T>
 12                 T
 13                 f(T t) {return 0;};
 14 };
 15 
 16 int main() {
 17     S<1> s1;
 18     S<2> s2;
 19     cout << s1.f(99) <<" "<< s2.f(99) << endl;
 20     return 0;
 21 }
```

---

The error message are accurate and problems are pointed out precisely.

```
enable_if.cc19:20: error: call of overloaded ‘f(int)’ is ambiguous
enable_if.cc:9:3: error: no type named ‘type’ in   
                         ‘struct std::enable_if<false, int>’
```

It seems just the problem of not-well-defined design and can easily be corrected. To deal with it,I can write partial specialized class template:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<int N> struct S{
        template<class T>
        T
        f(T t) {return 0;};
};
template<> struct S<1>{
        template<class T>
        T
        f(T t) {return 1;};
};
int main() {
    S<1> s1;
    S<2> s2;
    cout << s1.f(99) <<" "<< s2.f(99) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But for the cleanses and convenience, what about to enhance the enable_if template to support such new features urged by the wrong code at first?

- when `s1` call f,the more specialized one which return 1 in example can be used.
- when `s2` call f,the general one which return 0 will be used,even first one failed.

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could workaround the problem by:

1. Putting mutually exclusive SFINAE-constraints on your function template;
2. Forcing the evaluation of the `enable_if` to be performed at call time.

For instance:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<int N>
struct S
{
    template <class T>
    typename std::enable_if<N == 1 && std::is_same<T, T>::value, int>::type
    f(T t) {return 1;}

    template <class T>
    typename std::enable_if<N != 1, T>::type
    f(T t) {return 0;}
};
```

Here is a [**live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=e32f1a45a9d03be59f22472bd9e8f813-e54ee7a04e4b807da0930236d4cc94dc).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I suspect you had a typo in your code. Enable if should be paramterized on T, to compile: `typename enable_if<N==1,T>::type` instead of `typename enable_if<N==1,int>::type`

Just use the second overload with enable if, too, with inverted condition. It works:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<int N>
struct S{
                template<class T>
                typename enable_if<N==1,T>::type
                f(T t) {return 1;};

                template<class T>
                typename enable_if<N!=1,T>::type
                f(T t) {return 0;};
};

int main() {
    S<1> s1;
    S<2> s2;
    cout << s1.f(99) <<" "<< s2.f(99) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Notice, that the OP wants the return type to always be `int` when `N ==  1`

Comment: Considering the solution provided in the second code snipped (with specialized class), I assumed that the return type is always T.

Answer (score 0):

You can still do it without partial specialisation, but:

1. You must make sure only one of the functions ever exists (otherwise there's ambiguity)
2. You must make the `enable_if` condition depend on the template parameter.

This works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;


template <int N>
struct S
{
    template <typename T>
    typename enable_if<(sizeof(T)>0) && N==1, int>::type
    f(T t) { return 1; }

    template <typename T>
    typename enable_if<(sizeof(T)>0) && N!=1, T>::type
    f(T t) { return 0; }
};

int main()
{
    S<1> s1;
    S<2> s2;
    cout << s1.f(99) << " " << s2.f(99) << endl;
}
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/Dw2ELF)

Answer (score 0):

`std::enable_if` is only a tool to choose function overloads. It is implemented as a pure library solution coming from [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html). I think the rules for choosing the right overloads are not easy. But asking for changing this in certain cases when `enable_if` is involved would make it more complicated. So you best work with partial specialisation and disjunctive `enable_if`.